# How to compare inexact string values

Tags: c#, string, compare, contains

I want to compare two `string` values which are not exact For example I want to compare *Admin* to *Administrator*, this should return true or should execute.
I tried `contain` which is not working

```
 var prodcut = lstProducts.Where(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(appname.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();
```

Above code not working if `i.Name` is 'Admin' and `appname.ToLower()` is 'Administrator'. It just return null but want it should detect values.

Comment: Can you please add more samples, and also mentioned `which is not working` means

Comment: @sujithkarivelil - Above code not working if `i.Name` is Admin and `appname.ToLower()` is Administrator. It just return null.

Comment: if thats the input its works correct, `Admin` doesn't contains `Administrator` but `Administrator` should contains `Admin` na(common logic)?  Then why don't you try with `appname.ToLower().Contains(i.Name.ToLower())` lol

Comment: So it has to be the other way around.... just use `if(a.contains(b) || b.contains(a))`

Comment: @EpicKip - If you want you can I write your answer. Bcz you was first to suggest it.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil - Yeah, your comment helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @r15 Sure, thanks. Posted my answer

Comment: Consider comparing two strings with `Equals` where you can use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of `ToLower()`: `i.Name.Substring(0, 5).Equals(appname.Substring(0, 5), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: You might consider checking for StartsWith rather than Contains (I think StartsWith is a string method, but it would be easy to write). You probably also want to consider having a minimum number for matching characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check it both ways so if A contains B OR if B contains A you can use the [`||` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) (the `OR` operator) like so:

```
a.Contains(b) || b.Contains(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the strings the wrong way around (you're looking for `Adminstrator` in `Admin`)

You can do the check both ways around like this:

```
 lstProducts.Where(i => 
     i.Name.ToLower().Contains(appname.ToLower()) ||
     appname.ToLower().Contains(i.Name.ToLower())
 ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or just compare the first few characters:

```
lstProducts.Where(i => 
    i.Name.ToLower().SubString(0,5) == appname.ToLower().SubString(0,5))
).FirstOrDefault();
```

[Fuzzy matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is actually quite a complicated subject but there's a lot of research into the topic.